# matplotlib quiver arrow direction

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot grid of vectors. However when I load my files, vectors actually point to the 45 degree wrong direction, but following the patter from my data. In quiver howto, it is said it points 45 degrees when the vectors are the same, can this be changed?
Also when I tried to use some random number the quiver function acted quite randomly. (using numbers or generating angle grid by arctan(y/x)*180/3.1415). My grid of vectors should look like its rotating - vortex around the centre, instead it looks like antivortex blowing out of the centre.

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import ma
import scipy.io as c
import math


X,Y = meshgrid( arange(0,100,1),arange(0,100,1) )

ufile = np.genfromtxt(r'x.txt')  
vfile = np.genfromtxt(r'y.txt')

U = ufile
V = vfile
angle = (((abs(U)/U+1)/2)*((abs(V)/V+1)/2)*arctan(V/U)+((abs(V)/V+1)/2)*((abs(U)/U-1)/2)‌​*(-arctan(V/U)+math.pi)+((abs(V)/V-1)/2)*((abs(U)/U-1)/2)*(arctan(V/U)+math.pi)+(‌​(abs(U)/U+1)/2)*((abs(V)/V-1)/2)*(-arctan(V/U)+2*math.pi))*180/math.pi+90


scale = 10
figure()
Q = quiver( X[::scale, ::scale], Y[::scale, ::scale], U[::scale, ::scale], V[::scale, ::scale],
            pivot='mid', color='k', units='xy', headaxislength=20, angles=angle[::scale, ::scale] )
axis([0, 100, 0, 100])

show()
```

Comment: Can you supply a dummy set of x.txt and y.txt?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/blazzter/Home/x.txt https://sites.google.com/site/blazzter/Home/y.txt

Comment: also example in my question is obviously wrong with arctan function

Comment: this created right angle grid, its very clumsy .. `code` angle = (((abs(U)/U+1)/2)*((abs(V)/V+1)/2)*arctan(V/U)+((abs(V)/V+1)/2)*((abs(U)/U-1)/2)*(-arctan(V/U)+math.pi)+((abs(V)/V-1)/2)*((abs(U)/U-1)/2)*(arctan(V/U)+math.pi)+((abs(U)/U+1)/2)*((abs(V)/V-1)/2)*(-arctan(V/U)+2*math.pi))*180/math.pi+90